# Ethernet connection is disconnecting on reboot, on linux VM(virtual box)

Tags: linux, networking

My ethernet connection is disconnecting on every reboot and I have to enable it everytime when start the machine. I not familiar with linux networking. Please help
[Here is the image shows on reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsswJ.jpg)

I have to use "#nmtui" and activate the connection again and following figure shows [Second image is the result after activating again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcGA4.jpg)

It has to be done everytime after the reboot.
(Network connection is in NAT mode)

Answer (score 0):

In case of redhat types,You can go to configuration files of network interface /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts and you will see ifcfg-enp0s3 and there make ONBOOT=yes.
For Ubuntu /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 and do the same as above.

Comment: Okay got it, and can it also be done by "nmtui>edit connection>Automatically connect" by checking (X) at this Automatically Connect.